# camel spring-ws: handling exception

Tags: apache-camel, spring-ws, spring-camel

Is there a way to return a custom body (e.g. custom bean) and http status as 500 in camel + spring-ws?

I tried with

```
onException(RuntimeException.class).handled(true).process(new
     ExceptionProcessor()).marshal(jaxb);
```

and then in the processor
   public class ExceptionProcessor implements Processor {

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    RuntimeException e = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, RuntimeException.class);

    ExceptionHandler handler = ExceptionHandlerFactory.fromException(e);
    ExceptionType response = handler.handleException();


    if (exchange.hasOut()) {
        exchange.getOut().setBody(response);
    } else {
        exchange.getIn().getHeaders();
        exchange.getIn().setFault(true);
        exchange.getIn().setBody(response);
    }

}
```

}

but even if the body is what I want, the http status is always 200. 
Can you help me?

Some more info:
I'm using camel version  2.20.2

Answer (score 0):

```
exchange.setProperty(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, 500);
exchange.getOut().setFault(true);
```

should work for you.

Comment: still not working. If I set the fault to true the envelope body is even blank. In any case the http status is always 200. FYI I'm using camel  2.20.2